# date or time change.reload from disk error in c

Tags: c, disk

I use emulated Turbo C++ IDE 3.0 for development in C. I get the above mentioned error on when I run the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    char x;
    do
    {
        printf("enter the number i: ");
        scanf("%d",&i );
        printf("enter the number j: ");
        scanf("%d",&j);
        k=i+j;
        printf("Addition of given numbers :%d ",k);
        printf("\n Do you to continue : ");
        scanf("%c",&x);
    } while(x=='y'||x=='Y');    
    getch();
}
```

It was successfully compiled without errors or warnings. At run time, the problem arises after the statement `printf("\n Do you to continue : ");`.

When I enter a value for this, the error shows up. I tried in dev C++ but the problem prevails. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Please get yourself a better (or, at least, more modern) compiler than Turbo C!

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: i suggest you use `fgets()` to read from keyboard instead to keep things as simple as possible. then you do not need to care whether there is a left over carriage return or an invalid character in the buffer. then just use `atoi()` to convert the string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion

change

`scanf("%c",&x);`

to

`scanf(" %c",&x);`